# How do I display fields from a Commerce Cheque transaction using Views?

Tags: commerce

We have been processing payments in Drupal Commerce using the [Commerce Cheque](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cheque) module. For accounting purposes, we would like a view showing all checks received with check numbers, etc..

How do I configure a view to display fields from [Commerce Cheque](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cheque), specifically check number?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view of of Payment Transactions and filter by Payment Method = check.

The check reference number is stored in the field called Remote ID. Just add that field to the view.